# Count number of Slashes in the URL Using Regex

Tags: regex

I need to get number of slashes from the given url using regex alone.

```
For example URL looks like below:
/abc/123/ab1/bc2/efg

Required Result Should be : 5 (Number of slashes)
```

Here i am not going to handle the count by incrementing matches one by one by using anyother language.
Just i need to use regular expression to fetch the number of slashes.
Is it possible to fetch the count by using regex alone ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Regex can't count - this needs to be done in your actual language.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Depending on language you are using (if you are) you could call `length` or some variation of it on the matches and get number of matches back.

Comment: @GCP To spill my beans, I was thinking of splitting the string on forward slash, and then counting the size of the resulting array.  Easy to do in a language like Java, Python or C#.

Comment: Split the string with slash and get the array elements count

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well my approach in Java would be to replace all `/` in a String and do the math on length before and after.

Comment: @GCP Yup, that should work :-)

Answer (score 2):

Regex can't count.. it's just a way to validate input.

Simple and short way is to split you url :

```
String url = "/abc/123/ab1/bc2/efg"

var count = url.split("/").length-1
```

Comment: The language is the post or your answer is not specified.

Comment: Yes but split method is in  a lot of language

Comment: @LeoR. But maybe not in the one the OP is using: [tag:VBA] uses `Split(string, delimiter)`, [tag:PHP] uses `explode(delimiter, string)`, [tag:R] uses `strsplit(string, delimiter)`

Comment: Yes it's not the same synthax but the result is the same :) the best think is a more specified question...

Comment: @LeoR. it can cause confusion. Also `length` has a multitude of implementations... `len()`, `count()`, `sizeof()`, `UBound(x, y) - LBound(x, y) + 1`

Comment: it's true, i understand what you mean.. 
but if the answer was more precise it would be even simpler

Comment: @LeoR. I agree the OP should let us know which programming language is being used.